# Java and working with different instances

Tags: java, swing

I have a program where I can click on a button and it calls in a new panel, making the current one false through action listener. This panel uses up the whole size of the `JFrame`, giving me a form to fill out and buttons to press.

Is this the correct method to do this? Or is there a better way as I am running into bugs where the newly called `JPanel` appears on other `JPanel`s. I could use `setVisible(false)` but then certain elements such as buttons do not appear.

Comment: the proper way would be to use a proper Layout in my eyes. Since it seems that you want to "replace" the panel that is visible to the user the [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) might be fitting your needs.

Comment: The correct "method" to do this would pretty much depend on your goals. Should something else be visible? Should you not use a new JFrame instead? Should you be able to use all panels at the same time? Ask yourself these questions first.

Comment: @KalinVarbanov How do I use multiple JFrames?

Comment: See also [*The Use of Multiple Frames…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/230513)

Answer (score 3):

According to what you want, it appears to me you would probably want to look at [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) where you can swtich 2 or more panels in the frame.

> Conceptually, each component that a CardLayout manages is like a playing card or trading card in a stack, where only the top card is visible at any time. You can choose the card that is showing in any of the following ways:
>
> - By asking for either the first or last card, in the order it was added to the container
> - By flipping through the deck backwards or forwards
> - By specifying a card with a specific name